# Databound TreeView with List of List

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, objectlistview

I'm trying to get some hierarchical object structure into a `Winforms` `TreeView` (or some 3rd party treeview). Of course I could just build it node by node but I need to have it databound, so that I don't have to take care of a user adding some node(s) to the `TreeView`. My highest priority is to have data consistency between the data (represented by the Enumerable) and the  `TreeView` as a GUI component. If I change the List I want to get the tree updated and inserting Nodes into the tree the other way round.

My structure looks like this:

```
List<sourcelist> lists = new List<sourcelist>()
            {
                new sourcelist() {
                    name = "List1", 
                    items = new List<item>()
                {
                    new item() {source_key = "abc", name = "Pete"},
                }},
                new sourcelist() {
                    name = "List2"
                },
                new sourcelist() {
                    name = "List3", 
                    items = new List<item>()
                {
                    new item() {source_key = "y0h5l2VsrL", name = "Lisa"},
                    new item() {name = "Kara"},
                }}
            };
```

Basically some sourcelists that have a name an contain a list of items that have a name and a key

A lot of recommendations leaded me to [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) but I'm also open for better solutions.

I tried to it like this:

```
        //dataTreeListView1.ParentKeyAspectName = "pid";
        //dataTreeListView1.KeyAspectName = "id";
        dataTreeListView1.RootKeyValue = 0;

        dataTreeListView1.SetObjects(lists);
```

The tree just remains empty.
I think the major problem is that I can't set `KeyAspectName` and `ParentKeyAspectName` which would build up the tree's hierarchy.

I also tried to flatten the list and give it a structure with id and `ParentId` but didn't work out. Also my attempt inserting the List into a `DataSet` and binding this failed.

Help with this issue would really be appreciated.

Comment: For data bound ObjectListView components, I believe you have to assign the DataSource property instead of using SetObjects(). Take a look at [this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-bind-a-dataset-to-an-objectlistview). Not sure if it is suitable for your scenario though.

Comment: found this as well. didn't make the trick. thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a user adding some node(s) to the `TreeView`? Do you mean a developer or an end user? Also: What are `sourcelist` and `item`? And: are the data coming from a DBMS with joins?

Comment: I meant an end-user. I already built up the databinding myself not very elegant but still working out. thanks for your interest.

Comment: Don't use the data bound tree in this case. Just use your model objects directly. Create the columns you want to see, and setup your `CanExpandGetter` and `ChildrenGetter`. Piece of cake :)